# GitHub Action to run my Main.py when a file in another Repository is updated

Tags: python, github-actions

I have a python function that makes a request out to three URLs (they are JSON files containing data) hosted on another person's GitHub Repository (https://github.com/unitedstates/congress-legislators), pulls/transforms the data, and then inserts into a MongoDB Collection.

Is there a way to run my main.py on my repository whenever those three files are updated on the other person's GitHub Repository through a GitHub Action? The update schedule for the three JSON documents on the other person's GitHub Repository is not standard like every day, start of every month, every hour, etc. it's more random the update schedule.

Comment: Yes, you are looking for [repository_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) event. [This action](https://github.com/peter-evans/repository-dispatch) can help you trigger this event